# auto login and hashed password (cakephp 2)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

with cake 1.3 for autologin facebook users i get the user info from database:

```
$userInfo = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'fields' =>array('User.username','User.password'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'source_id' => $fb_user_id,
        'source' => "facebook",
    )
));
```

- password comming from this select is hashed.

and i use this method for authentication

```
$this->Auth->login($userInfo);
```

but now with  cake 2

```
var_dump($this->Auth->login($userInfo));
```

always return false;

i 'm not sure but i think that now the login() method need a clear password??

any solution? and excuse my English

Comment: what is role of facebook here?

Comment: i use facebook for authentication http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Try `$this->Auth->login($userInfo['User'])`, to login user in cakephp 2.0 you should use array with users data, without mention model

If its will not help then check if your Auth component configuration is right...

I use

```
 $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'all' => array(
            'userModel' => 'User',
                 ),
                 'Form'
      );
$this->Auth->loginAction = {url};
$this->Auth->logoutAction = {url}
```